# What happens if the Hulk were to swallow the Tesseract, and then return to human form?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-incredible-hulk, the-avengers-2012

When the Hulk is first approached in *The Avengers* movie the following exchange happens<sup>[1](http://www.moviequotesandmore.com/the-avengers-quotes.html#.UDZLx8HN9WA)</sup>:

> Natasha Romanoff: Doctor, we're facing a potential global catastrophe.
>
> Bruce Banner: Well, those I actively try to avoid.
>
> Natasha Romanoff: This is the Tesseract.
> [she shows him a photo of the Tesseract on her cell phone]
>
> Natasha Romanoff: It has the potential energy to wipe out the planet.
>
> **Bruce Banner: What does Fury want me to do? Swallow it?**
>
> Natasha Romanoff: Well, he wants you to find it. It's been taken. It omits a gamma signature that's too weak for us to trace. There's no one that knows gamma radiation like you do. If there was, that's where I'd be.
>
> Bruce Banner: So Fury isn't after the monster?

What happens if the Hulk swallows the Tesseract(the energy source cube from The Avengers movie) and then morphs back to human form?

My idea: Hulk wont need to pull ambient-gamma radiation to transform again. Will have it inside. Would need to eat an alien to help digesting.

Comment: If it could fit down his throat, he wouldn't return to human form until he exhumes it because he would be in a constant state of agitation and rage from the pain.

Comment: The Tesseract would go whereever his additional mass goes when he reverts. Which, if I'm not mistaken, is into the Tesseract. So the Tesseract would go into itself, sort of like when Farnsworth and Alternafarnsworth pulled the paraboxes out from inside each other. Additionally, there would be a stupid Whedon one-liner, and a sight gag reminiscent of a Bugs Bunny cartoon, probably involving belching.

Comment: @JohnO Where did we learn that the Hulk's additional mass goes into the Tesseract?

Comment: @JohnO has it been established in a movie that Hulk's additional mass goes to the Tesseract when he reverts to Bruce Banner?

Comment: @Wilerson There is no in-movie explanation. Nor are the rules of the Hulk consistent enough to make intelligent guesses. If I were the writer (I'm not) I would explain such a phenomenon as the creature in question consisting of a few million tons of exotic (invisible) sub-atomic particles in a giant cloud (possibly reaching outside Earth's orbit). When the transformation happens, those particles would coalesce and change into physical matter comprising the larger creature. But such a story doesn't really work with the Hulk, does it? Nor would it explain what happens if he ate the Tesseract.

Comment: @johno So what you're saying is that that's not how it works in the comic books.

Comment: Well, according to Marvel Zombies, when the Hulk eats a lot and then reverts to Banner, the result is that Banner's smaller stomach rips open and it all spills back out. Just sayin'.

Comment: If Hulk ate the tesseract and somehow digested it, I'm pretty sure the result would be a collapse of space-time.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck you mean a black hole? Then only releasing antimatter-dilithium reactor from a galaxy class spaceship would counter that.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik NO. The tesseract is an infinity stone. The one that controls space... as in space-time itself. Its destruction would literally cause the destruction of space-time itself. The universe would collapse and space (or volume/mass/geometric relationships) would literally cease to have any meaning in the Marvel universe. Alternatively, the Hulk cannot digest it and it just results in an intestinal blockage. The local hospital would have their hands full with that one.

Comment: I'd like to observe that there is an instance of an infinity stone being eaten in the comics, so there is a basis for which to answer the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it could fit down his throat, he wouldn't return to human form until he excretes it because he would be in a constant state of agitation and rage from the pain.